# Retrieving last items from XMPP PubSub Node with Smack always returns only a single item

Tags: java, xmpp, publish-subscribe, smack

I'm using the latest Smack (4.1) for my Android application.

When retrieving persistent items from a node, does it only return the latest published items for each user? Right now, when I try to call getItems, I seem to only get the latest published event from each user. I would like to retrieve *all* of the items from the node, even if there's more than one item for each user.

This is the code I'm using currently for retrieval:

```
PubSubManager manager = new PubSubManager(connectionManager.getConnection());  
node = manager.getNode(nodeList);  
Collection<PayloadItem<EventItem>> eventItems = node.getItems(25);  
Log.e(TAG, "Collection size: " + eventItems.size());  
List<PayloadItem<EventItem>> payloadList = new ArrayList<>();  

for(PayloadItem<EventItem> payload : eventItems) {  
     eventItemList.add(payload.getPayload());  
}
```

This is my node configure form:

```
ConfigureForm configureForm = new ConfigureForm(DataForm.Type.submit);  
        configureForm.setAccessModel(AccessModel.open);  
        configureForm.setDeliverPayloads(true);  
        configureForm.setNotifyRetract(true);  
        configureForm.setPersistentItems(true);  
        configureForm.setPublishModel(PublishModel.open);
```

As you can tell, setPersistentItems is true. If one user submits two items to a node and then calls getItems, only the latest of their published items is received. The debug shows that I only receive the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<iq to="pubsub.example.com" id="4cw4Z-27" type="get">  
   <pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">  
   <items node="TESTNODE" max_items="25" />  
   </pubsub>  
</iq>  


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<iq from="pubsub.example.com" to="afa@example.com/Smack" id="4cw4Z-27" type="result">  
   <pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">  
      <items node="TESTNODE">  
         <item id="bool@example.com/Smack">  
            <newevent xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/newevent" xml:lang="en">  
               <sender>bool@example.com</sender>  
               <title>Test Title 2</title>  
               <description>Test description</description>  
            </newevent>  
         </item>  
      </items>  
   </pubsub>  
</iq>
```

This is the only thing I receive in the debug. No other items present except for the latest published one for that particular user and other users.

It's clear that I am receiving the items stored in the node, however the server only returns the latest published item for each user. I would like to retrieve all items published to the node regardless if it's the latest one for that user or not.

Is this a server setting issue?
I appreciate any advice or suggestions.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was setting the JID of the payload item to the User's JID. As a result, I was overwriting the previous ID's and the previous submissions from the user was being overwritten. I set the PayLoadItem's ItemID to null and that let the server generate a unique ID each time, so the previous items would not be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

This could possible be a server limitation. XEP-60 6.5.7 makes `max_items` a optional feature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Flow. I am currently using eJabberd and set max_items to 100. However, that didn't solve the issue unfortunately. Do you have any suggestions on how to overcome the limitation? Or maybe an alternative method? I'm considering switching to an MUC unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, did you call https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/dailybuilds/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/pubsub/ConfigureForm.html#setMaxItems(int) ?

Comment: Yeah I added that into the configureform when I created a new node. I also have the two options enabled for eJabberd configuration server-side: 
{max_items_node, 1000},
{max_items, 100}. It still only gets the latest item for that specific  user

Comment: Then, without me having a closer look at xep60, I recommend you look at the component providing PubSub.

Comment: Hey Flow, I actually ended up figuring out the problem. After carefully looking over the documents, I realized that I was overwriting the ID's by not letting the server generate them. So I set the ItemID for payload item as null and now it works! Previously, I had the ID set to the user's JID, which is why it was being overwritten. Thank you!!